# How can I run an executable from RAM using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I run an executable from RAM using C++?

The executable is in RAM, and I know the address, how do I call into the program from mine?

Comment: Given you've tagged this as c#, as this exe generated via Codedom?

Comment: Just curious - what is the operating system and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'd guess trying to crack some application (see Armen's comments on Martin's reply).

Comment: You are actually accessing another application instance. Which should be done by accessing process.

Comment: Judging by this and his other questions it sounds like he's trying to write some sort of malware in c#. E.g. "Hello, I have c# program(.exe) , i will give it to other people, and want that exe fork only where it runed first time,"

Comment: Armen, could you please state what you are trying to achieve by doing this? Otherwise we have to assume that it would be better not to help you in the first place, but close this question instead.

Comment: @Adrian. His technical question is the same, regardless of whether or not he has some magical story of why it is necessary.

Comment: @devinb: So we should help him write malware or crack applications?

Answer (score 10):

This sort of things comes normally out of the dark corners of the world. ;-)

In combination with tools like metasploit it would be great to create process just out of ram and so a couple of guys tried to reimplement all the stuff that happens down in CreateProcess(). After a while they just found out that it is much too complex (see [this PDF](http://pentest.cryptocity.net/files/exploitation/winasm-1.0.1.pdf) site 12f) to get this to work and they tried to find another solution and here it is:
They call a normal CreateProcess() with a common program (e.g. notepad.exe), but they start it with ThreadSuspended.
Then they injected a new thread into this process, which will be filled up from memory. Afterwards they told this thread to run and so they got a new process filled from memory.

So this is just the big picture and it is a whole mess (and normally not the right way) to do this stuff. If you really interested in this part, then you have an idea to search for.

And by the way, don't think you can do this in C#. This is normally done in C/C++ or even Assembler...

Comment: BTW, could you specify what is so hard about the first approach?

Comment: @jpalecek: What do you mean with *first approach*? If you mean creating a process on yourself. Than i can only say that i remember of an article, where some smart guys just gave up. Maybe some keywords in my article can help you to find it again. If you meant to start a process with ThreadSuspended, than go and find out how you inject a new thread into an existing process. Cause this is also not quite easy (but easier than trying to create a process on yourself).

Comment: By the first approach, I meant creating the process myself. I googled a bit and found this: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/585637-execute-binary-code http://pentest.cryptocity.net/files/exploitation/winasm-1.0.1.pdf It seems the fork()-like part is hard. Not sure whether OP needs forking.

Comment: @jpalecek: Your second link is exactly the document i had in mind when i wrote my answer. I'm going to update it.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean that you have loaded the contents of the EXE file into RAM and now want to run that executable?

Since you're talking about an EXE, I assume you're running under Windows. To my knowledge, Windows can't do this -- your only option is to save the executable back to a file and run that (using `CreateProcess`, for example).

*Edit* Here is how you would run the process.

In C++:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if(!CreateProcess("myfilename.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, 
    NULL, &si, &pi ))
{
    // An error occurred
}
```

In C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("myfilename.exe");
```

Comment: yesssssssssss you right!  how i can use CreateProcess? 
THANK YOU

Comment: please not all problem is i do not have that exe in hard drive,

Comment: Are you the author of that other process? If so, it would be much better to communicate with it so that it writes the resources back to hard disk. Or use the same original resource from hard disk in the first place.

Comment: no dear Adrian, i am not author of other process. 
how can i do it in this way?

Comment: Thanks you Martin, see you write "myfilename.exe" , i do not want this, i want inject that exe into my program then call it, is this possible??

Comment: "Inject it into your program" -- what do you mean by that? "myfilename.exe" is just an example -- choose any filename you like, then write your EXE from memory to that file. If you're using C++, you could use ostream::write or fwrite to write the file. After you've written the file out, use CreateProcess to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean communicating with another application that is running at the same time as yours? That depends on which operating system you are using. In any case, Wikipedia has an article on [Interprocess Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), which shows some basic techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would run it from disk. Your program doesn't know whether it's already loaded (i.e. in RAM) or on disk. This is abstracted away by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Mabye this could help you: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory

PS: Writing an malware is not illegal (im most countries ;) ) using is!